# Repeating jQuery condensed using a common id

Tags: jquery

So, I have following simple jQuery where a common `id="private_menu_"` is used. What would be a good way to condense this repeating jQuery?

```
<a href="#private_menu_address" id="address">Menu 1</a>
<a href="#private_menu_name"  id="name">Menu 2</a>
<a href="#private_menu_country"  id="country">Menu 3</a>
<a href="#private_menu_email"  id="email">Menu 4</a>

<div id="private_menu_address">address</div>
<div id="private_menu_name"> name</div>
<div id="private_menu_country">country</div>
<div id="private_menu_email">email</div>

<script>
jQuery("#address").click(function () {      
    jQuery('#private_menu_address').show();
    jQuery('#private_menu_name').hide();
    jQuery('#private_menu_country').hide();
    jQuery('#private_menu_email').hide();       
    });
jQuery("#name").click(function () {     
    jQuery('#private_menu_address').hide();
    jQuery('#private_menu_name').show();
    jQuery('#private_menu_country').hide();
    jQuery('#private_menu_email').hide();       
    }); 
jQuery("#country").click(function () {      
    jQuery('#private_menu_address').hide();
    jQuery('#private_menu_name').hide();
    jQuery('#private_menu_country').show();
    jQuery('#private_menu_email').hide();       
    }); 
jQuery("#email").click(function () {        
    jQuery('#private_menu_address').hide();
    jQuery('#private_menu_name').hide();
    jQuery('#private_menu_country').hide();
    jQuery('#private_menu_email').show();       
    });
</script>
```

All it does is that when an anchor is clicked, it shows the selected div and hide everything else. It works fine but I just wanted to make it clean.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seperate the selectors with a comma and use the [**attribute starts with**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

```js
 jQuery("#address,#name,#country,#email").click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   jQuery('[id^="private_menu_"]').hide();
   jQuery('#private_menu_' + id).show();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#private_menu_address" id="address">Menu 1</a>
<a href="#private_menu_name" id="name">Menu 2</a>
<a href="#private_menu_country" id="country">Menu 3</a>
<a href="#private_menu_email" id="email">Menu 4</a>

<div id="private_menu_address">address</div>
<div id="private_menu_name">name</div>
<div id="private_menu_country">country</div>
<div id="private_menu_email">email</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Learned new things. Appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you how `jQuery('[id^="private_menu_"]').hide();` works? or what the logic behind it?

Comment: @steveKim, `^`,`$`, and `*` are like regex selectors. In regex, `^` means **starts with**, `$` means **ends with**, and `*` means **contains**

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.